# Gralloc Lock error in phonegap-android application

Tags: android, cordova

I am facing this error on few mobiles (android 4.4 os) on rest of android os it works

Error :  [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933

it makes me stop navigating from one screen to other.

The below image could help.[image]

Please let me out of this with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Try by adding number of seconds sleep.

change **onSurfaceDestroyed()** with

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
    Log.d("TEST_MESSAGE", "Engine.onSurfaceDestroyed()");
    try{
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception ie){ }
    mVisible = false;
    if (myDrawTask != null) {
        myDrawTask.cancel(false);
    }
}
```

It works for me,

From : [How to handle or prevent the fatal error “Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587598/how-to-handle-or-prevent-the-fatal-error-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv/21648207#21648207)

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you put that? It looks like a horrible idea to send the currentThread to sleep just to throttle the spamming but maybe I got it wrong.